# `vint` linter just quits due to a vim plugin incompatibility

Tags: linux, plugin-syntastic

*[Vim 8.0.1 / Syntastic 3.9.0-19 / Vundle 0.5 / vint 0.3.19 on Arch Linux]*

My vim linter seems to be broken and I don't quite understand why. 
It's been working fine in its present configuration, until this morning.

I get the following error message, when I write any buffer identified
as `vim` filetype to disk:

> syntastic: warning: checker vim/vint: unrecognized error format
>   (crashed checker?)

It is also the content of `:messages` in buffer.

"Startpage"-ing it returned zero relevant result.

The pertinent `~/.vimrc` section ...

```
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git'
Plugin 'Townk/vim-autoclose' 
Plugin 'dougireton/vim-chef'
Plugin 'jimhester/lintr'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX'
Plugin 'Kuniwak/vint'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Syntastic is aware of $USER $PATH:

```
:echo syntastic#util#system('echo "$PATH"')
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/opt/bin:/opt/scripts
```

The runtime path includes Vundle:

```
:set runtimepath?
runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim,~/.vim/bundle/syntastic,~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe,~/.vim/bundle/vim-autoclose,~/.vim/bundle/vim-chef,~/.vim/bundle/lintr,~/.vim/bundle/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX,~/.vim/bundle/vint,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim81,/usr/share/vim/vim81/pack/dist/opt/matchit,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after,~.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim,~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/after,~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/after,~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/after,~/.vim/bundle/vim-autoclose/after,~/.vim/bundle/vim-chef/after,~/.vim/bundle/lintr/after,~/.vim/bundle/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX/after,~/.vim/bundle/vint/after
```

The cloned git repo in `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` is up to date.
The `vint` executable is correctly located at `/usr/bin/vint` and I inserted the following in `~/.vimrc`:

```
  let g:syntastic_vim_checkers = ['vint']
```

so that issuing ex cmd `:SyntasticInfo [vim]` does yield `vint` and the correct filetype, "vim".

I am stumped. Has anybody seen this before ?

Comment: The error message probably means exactly what it says, either `vint` changed output format when I wasn't looking, or it just crashed.  Feel free to post to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues) if you jcare to find out what's going on.  This isn't appropriate for [vim.se].

Comment: @lcd047: issue opened on https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Kuniwak/vint` lint checker breaks (im my setup) when parsing non-ASCII characters. It happens as soon as even one character outside the 0-127 ASCII range (plus a few such as "_", etc. ) appear in the vim-script, no matter where, i.e. inside or outside comments.

As suggested by @lcd047, I added debug option flags to my `~/.vimrc` to catch more verbose messages:

```
"let g:syntastic_debug = 3
"let g:syntastic_debug_file = '~/.vim/syntastic.log'
```

The content of `:messages` revealed:

> "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vint/encodings/decoding_strategy.py",
>   line 77, in decode', ' return
>   bytes_seq.decode(encoding=encoding_part.decode(encoding=''ascii''))',
>   'UnicodeDecodeError: ''ascii'' codec can''t decode byte 0xc2 in
>   position 33: ordinal not in range(128)', '']
>
> syntastic: warning:
>   checker vim/vint: unrecognized error format (crashed checker?)

As it turns out, byte 0xc2 is the first byte of the two-byte non-ASCII character "º" that I had just mapped as in: `inoremap <C-º> <Esc>`.

The mapping worked just fine ... and `vint` just quit.  In retrospect I find it curious that in support of the suspicion that `vint` was at fault, running `:echo system('vint $USER/.vimrc --json')` in-buffer, and `$ vint $USER/.vimrc` from console, produced the exact same error.

So I opened an [issue](https://github.com/Kuniwak/vint/issues/292) at the `vint` GitHub repo.

---

In the end the `Kuniwak/vint` lint checker works fine. Another plugin causes an incompatibility and is at fault: `Townk/vim-autoclose`.  It somehow makes `vint` crash when parsing non-ASCII characters. Also for instance, syntax highlighting groups targeting those same non-ASCIIs do not work when `autoclose` is loaded. It also causes weird results when used in conjunction with YouCompleteMe.

Solution: replace `Townk/vim-autoclose` with `Raimondi/delimitMate`.

Comment: Shouldn't you actually wait for the reply of author before posting your analyses left and right? For what it's worth, my `vint` can happily parse the line `inoremap <C-º> <Esc>`.

Comment: Since you can reproduce the problem in a terminal, this has nothing to do with Vim.  Your `vint` installation is broken.  If you ask nicely, `vint`'s author will probably tell you how / why.  Maybe claiming it's a _feature_ was not a step in that direction.